# ultima alteração de registro da tabela usando função MAX

Tags: oracle11g

Estou tentando trazer todos os registros de uma tabela pegando a ultima alteração  para isso utilizei a função MAX() porém ela não está me retornando nenhum resultado.

Estas são minhas condições:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       U.USS_CODIGO,
       T.CON_CODIGO, 
       t.CON_SEQUENCIA,
       t.PLA_NUMERO, 
       T.PPC_DT_ALT, 
       t.PDT_CODIGO,
       t.PPC_DT_VIGENCIA,
       T.PPC_VAL_MENSALIDADE, 
       t.PPC_IDADE_MIN 
  FROM preco_produto_contrato t, 
       CONTRATANTE C, 
       USUARIO U 
 WHERE T.PPC_DT_ALT = (SELECT MAX(T.PPC_DT_ALT)
                         FROM preco_produto_contrato t 
                        WHERE T.con_codigo = c.con_codigo 
                          AND t.PPC_DT_EXC IS NULL 
                          AND U.CON_CODIGO = C.CON_CODIGO 
                          AND U.CON_CODIGO = T.CON_CODIGO 
                          AND c.con_dt_exc IS NULL 
                          AND t.pla_numero in (105) 
                          AND t.con_sequencia = c.con_sequencia)
```

Comment: Amigo, adicione mais informações, tais como estrutura das tabelas, exemplo dos dados, resultado esperado... E a select completa.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT U.USS_CODIGO, T.CON_CODIGO,
   t.CON_SEQUENCIA,t.PLA_NUMERO, T.PPC_DT_ALT,
   t.PDT_CODIGO,t.PPC_DT_VIGENCIA,T.PPC_VAL_MENSALIDADE,
   t.PPC_IDADE_MIN   
FROM preco_produto_contrato t, CONTRATANTE C, USUARIO U
WHERE T.PPC_DT_ALT = (SELECT MAX(T.PPC_DT_ALT)FROM preco_produto_contrato t
      WHERE T.con_codigo = c.con_codigo
            AND t.PPC_DT_EXC IS NULL
            AND U.CON_CODIGO = C.CON_CODIGO
            AND U.CON_CODIGO = T.CON_CODIGO
          AND c.con_dt_exc IS NULL
          AND t.pla_numero in (105)
            AND t.con_sequencia = c.con_sequencia)

Comment: Amigo, quando for necessária a adição de mais informações na sua questão você pode editá-la. Neste caso a SELECT informada no seu comentário deveria ser acrescentada na sua questão. Já providenciei a edição. Logo que um moderador aprovar a SELECT aparecerá no corpo da questão.

Comment: O alias da tabela preco_produto_contato não pode ser o mesmo , no caso "t" , para as duas instâncias da tabela , select principal e sub , troque o da sub por algo como "t2" .

Comment: usa um `order by desc`.

Answer (score 0):

Mas se executar o subquerie:

```
(SELECT MAX(T.PPC_DT_ALT)
FROM preco_produto_contrato t 
WHERE T.con_codigo = c.con_codigo 
AND t.PPC_DT_EXC IS NULL 
AND U.CON_CODIGO = C.CON_CODIGO 
AND U.CON_CODIGO = T.CON_CODIGO 
AND c.con_dt_exc IS NULL 
AND t.pla_numero in (105) 
AND t.con_sequencia = c.con_sequencia)
```

Dá alguma coisa?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Legal você querer ajudar, mas você usou uma resposta para fazer um comentário. Você poderá postar comentários quando tiver [um pouco mais de pontos de reputação](http://br.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor utilize o campo de resposta somente para postar uma solução ao problema de que a pergunta trata.

Answer (score 0):

Alan,

acredito que a consulta que você deseja seja algo assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    U.USS_CODIGO,
    T.CON_CODIGO, 
    T.CON_SEQUENCIA,
    T.PLA_NUMERO, 
    T.PPC_DT_ALT, 
    T.PDT_CODIGO,
    T.PPC_DT_VIGENCIA,
    T.PPC_VAL_MENSALIDADE, 
    T.PPC_IDADE_MIN 
FROM 
    PRECO_PRODUTO_CONTRATO T
    JOIN CONTRATANTE C ON T.CON_SEQUENCIA = C.CON_SEQUENCIA
    JOIN USUARIO U ON U.CON_CODIGO = C.CON_CODIGO AND U.CON_CODIGO = T.CON_CODIGO
WHERE 
    T.PPC_DT_ALT = (SELECT MAX(T2.PPC_DT_ALT) FROM PRECO_PRODUTO_CONTRATO T2 WHERE T2.CON_CODIGO = T.CON_CODIGO)
    AND T.PPC_DT_EXC IS NULL
    AND C.CON_DT_EXC IS NULL 
    AND T.PLA_NUMERO IN (105);
```

Como o usuário Motta comentou, não utilize o mesmo alias da sua query principal em sua subquery.

Além disso, para deixar a consulta mais legível, use JOINs para separar cláusulas de junção de cláusulas de filtro.