# Selecionar último registro da tabela

Tags: oracle, select

Um `SELECT` que apresenta as entradas do produto, porém, o `SELECT` apresenta todas as datas de entrada, mas eu queria pegar o último registro da tabela. O banco é Oracle, já usei `LIMIT 1` e também `FIRST` e nada de dar certo.

Neste `SELECT` é listado 7 registros. Como selecionar para aparecer apenas o último?

```
SELECT
  CAB.DTNEG, ITE.CODPROD, PRO.DESCRPROD, ITE.VLRIPI, ITE.ALIQIPI, ITE.VLRIPI
FROM
  TGFCAB CAB, TGFITE ITE, TGFPRO PRO
WHERE
  CAB.CODTIPOPER IN(47,12) AND CAB.NUNOTA = ITE.NUNOTA AND ITE.CODPROD = 4600035 AND PRO.CODPROD = ITE.CODPROD
ORDER BY 1
```

O resultado é o abaixo:

```
DTNEG       CODPROD DESCRPROD   VLRIPI  ALIQIPI VLRIPI
14/03/2022  4600035 DISCO 1TB   444,14  7,50    444,14
16/03/2022  4600035 DISCO 1TB   444,14  7,50    444,14
04/04/2022  4600035 DISCO 1TB   444,13  7,50    444,13
13/04/2022  4600035 DISCO 1TB   444,14  7,50    444,14
27/05/2022  4600035 DISCO 1TB   96,13   6,50    96,13
02/06/2022  4600035 DISCO 1TB   384,50  6,50    384,50
07/06/2022  4600035 DISCO 1TB   384,50  6,50    384,50
```

Quero que liste apenas os resultados da data 07/06/202.

Comment: Veja se ajuda   https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131237/ultima-altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-registro-da-tabela-usando-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-max

Comment: ORDER BY DTNEG DESC LIMIT 1. Parece que você que a data mais recente.

Comment: Além disso, se você quer somente os resultados de uma data, você deveria usar essa data na cláusula `WHERE`.

Answer (score -1):

Uma solução possível.

Solução com "max" e um subselect , pode ser uma sql lenta se não houver um índice apropriado , mas como NUNOTA deve ser PK deve atender.
Tem a vantagem de ser genêrica , serveria para uma lista de produtos e poder trazer todos os dados requeridos.

```
SELECT CAB.DTNEG, ITE.CODPROD, PRO.DESCRPROD, ITE.VLRIPI, ITE.ALIQIPI, ITE.VLRIPI
FROM TGFCAB CAB, TGFITE ITE, TGFPRO PRO 
WHERE CAB.CODTIPOPER IN( 47,12) 
AND CAB.NUNOTA = ITE.NUNOTA 
AND ITE.CODPROD = 4600035 
AND PRO.CODPROD = ITE.CODPROD 
AND CAB.DTNEG = (SELECT MAX(CAB2.DTNEG)
                 FROM TGFCAB CAB2
                 WHERE CAB2.NUNOTA = CAB.NUNOTA)

ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Pessoal consegui da seguinte forma abaixo, mudei todo o código, porém o resultado apresentado foi o que eu queria, ficou assim:

```
WITH Y AS
( SELECT ITE.CODPROD, CAB.DTENTSAI, ITE.VLRUNIT
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITE.CODPROD ORDER BY CAB.DTENTSAI DESC) AS ORDEMY
FROM TGFCAB CAB INNER JOIN TGFITE ITE ON ITE.NUNOTA=CAB.NUNOTA AND ITE.ATUALESTOQUE=1 AND CAB.CODTIPOPER IN(4,12)AND ITE.CODPROD = 4600035
)

SELECT * FROM Y
WHERE
Y.ORDEMY IN (1)
ORDER BY Y.CODPROD, Y.DTENTSAI DESC
```

A consulta retornou o resultado abaixo que eu esperava:
[Resultado do select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bID3Q.png)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).