# Retornar a classificação do produto

Tags: sql, oracle

Preciso retornar a classificação de um produto, em que o valor cálculado de quantidade é o maior.

Tenho a seguinte Query

```
SELECT PROD_CLASS.PRODUTO, PROD_CLASS.CLASSIFICACAO, COUNT(PROD_CLASS.CLASSIFICACAO) AS QUANTIDADE
FROM PRODUTO_CLASSIFICACAO PROD_CLASS
WHERE PROD_CLASS.PRODUTO IN (20,6,9)
GROUP BY PROD_CLASS.PRODUTO, PROD_CLASS.CLASSIFICACAO
```

---

Que retorna:

| PRODUTO | CLASSIFICACAO | QUANTIDADE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | C | 45 |
| 6 | B | 10 |
| 9 | B | 1 |
| 9 | E | 15 |
| 20 | A | 19 |
| 20 | D | 1 |

Preciso que retorne:

| PRODUTO | CLASSIFICACAO |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | C |
| 9 | E |
| 20 | A |

Comment: Subselect com MAX , veja se ajuda ... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131237/ultima-altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-registro-da-tabela-usando-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-max

Answer (score 0):

Sem ter como testar , pronto para negativações (justas), as subqueries totalizaradoras como tabela virtuais e testando o MAX da quantidade.
Respondida pois pode ser útil em casos de maximizações ou minimizações de valores agregados.

```
SELECT PRODUTO,CLASSIFICACAO,QUANTIDADE
    FROM
    (SELECT PROD_CLASS.PRODUTO, PROD_CLASS.CLASSIFICACAO, COUNT(PROD_CLASS.CLASSIFICACAO) AS QUANTIDADE
     FROM PRODUTO_CLASSIFICACAO PROD_CLASS
     WHERE PROD_CLASS.PRODUTO IN (20,6,9)
     GROUP BY PROD_CLASS.PRODUTO, PROD_CLASS.CLASSIFICACAO) TAB_AUX 
     WHERE QUANTIDADE = (SELECT MAX(QUANTIDADE)
                         FROM
                         (SELECT PROD_CLASS.PRODUTO, PROD_CLASS.CLASSIFICACAO, COUNT(PROD_CLASS.CLASSIFICACAO) AS QUANTIDADE
                          FROM PRODUTO_CLASSIFICACAO PROD_CLASS2
                          WHERE PROD_CLASS.PRODUTO IN (20,6,9)
                          GROUP BY PROD_CLASS.PRODUTO, PROD_CLASS.CLASSIFICACAO) TAB_AUX2
                         WHERE TAB_AUX2.PRODUTO = TAB_AUX.PRODUTO
                         AND   TAB_AUX2.CLASSIFICACAO = TAB_AUX.CLASSIFICACAO
                         GROUP BY PRODUTO, CLASSIFICACAO)
```